# If $F$ is a field with characteristic $p$, $F(\alpha)$ is also a field with characteristic $p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $F$ is a field with characteristic $p$ and $\alpha$ is element of an extension of $F$, $F(\alpha)$ is also a field with characteristic $p$?

At the first glance, it seems obvious, because $F(\alpha)$ is the field generated by $F$ and $\alpha$. The problem is this element $\alpha$ which doesn't need to be in an extension of characteristic $p$.

I'm a little confused, I need help.

Thanks

Comment: why downvoted??

Comment: I upvoted to counter the downvote which I also don't understand.

Comment: @BrunoStonek yes, thank you

Answer (score 6):

Hint: You have that $F$ is a subfield of $F(\alpha)$ and the additive order of $1$ is the same whether you are thinking about $1$ in $F$ or $F(\alpha)$.

Comment: I didn't understand very well your hint, please can you explain a little bit more? thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

A field $F$ has characteristic $p$ exactly when the kernel of the canonical ring map
$$
\phi:\Bbb Z\longrightarrow F,
\qquad\text{$\phi(n)=n\cdot1_F$ if $n\geq0$}
$$
is the ideal $\Bbb Zp$. This makes obvious that if $F\subseteq F^\prime$ is an inclusion of fields, then the characteristics of $F$ and $F^\prime$ are the same.